# Reverse Edge Collapse

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

I am trying to make edges such that parts of my mesh are smooth and rounded while others are sharper. Is there a way to perform an operation that does the opposite of an edge collapse? I guess the problem would be selecting which lines go to which vertex.

Edit:

Start like this:

[image: Before]

and change it to this:

[image: After]

Comment: Could you please add some screen captures as an example of what you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can '*rip fill*', with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Once done you'll eventually need to remake quad : select the needed faces and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]